# How to pass arbitrary number of parameters to node-mssql

Tags: node-mssql

I have a function where a text input is split into subtexts of each 51 characters and passed to mssql to update an arbitrary number of fields like so:

```
UPDATE some table
    SET 
    EXP1 = 'inputvalue1' 
    EXP2 = 'inputvalue2',
    EXP3 = 'inputvalue3',
    EXP4 = 'inputvalue4',
    EXP5 = 'inputvalue5',
    EXP6 = 'inputvalue6',

    WHERE id = @id
```

The problem is for shorter texts I do not need to update all of the fields. How can I set the query and the parameters arbitrarily in node-mssql so I can make full use of sql-injection prevention?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question

```
await sql.query`UPDATE TABLE 
${textElements.match(/.{51}/g).map((element,i) => `EXP${i+1}=${element}`).join(",") }
where id = {id}`
```